# How to get list of all search keyword in Lucene?

Tags: search, lucene, indexing

I need the list of all search keyword(term) i.e. indexed in lucene index. I googled for it. but, i didn't get the solution. Is it possible to get the list of all search term?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need the function [IndexReader.terms()](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_1/api/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#terms%28%29) that gives you an enumeration of all the terms. I highly recommend using the [Luke](http://www.getopt.org/luke/) interactive Lucene front-end for exploring Lucene indexes.